# Use a composite key as the primary key or have 2 foreign keys and another seperate field as the primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-key

I have the following tables:

| student |

- studentID(P)
- Name
- ...

| Jobs |

- JobID(P)
- Job_Name
- ...

| Application |

- JobID
- StudentID
- ApplicationID
- ...

should I get rid of ApplicationID in the Application table and use JobID and StudentID as a composite primary key or should I have these as foreign keys and use ApplicationID as the primary key?

note: If it makes a difference I will be applying constraints such as students can accept only one application, have 3 weeks after it being offered to accept it etc.

Thanks

Comment: Given that the Application table could also be referenced from somewhere else at some point, I would keep the single PK ApplicationID.

Comment: awesome, thanks - @KouberSaparev if you put as an answer i'll vote as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From theoretical point of view, the `ApplicationID` primary key might seem redundant at this stage (given there are just these 3 tables), thus you might be tempted to drop it and switch to the more natural composite primary key `(StudentID, JobID)`.

However, there are 2 strong practical counter arguments to that.

1. Your data structure might grow beyond these 3 tables and at some point the `Application` table itself could be referenced from somewhere else. That would mean that every foreign key referencing that table should also be composite and consist of the `StudentID` and `JobID` combination, **everywhere**.
2. Every application beyond the SQL layer should map to the `Application` table based on this composite primary key in order to view / edit or delete entries from it.

It is up to you to decide how strong the 2 points above are, for your specific case. If the probability that the `Application` table will be referenced tends to 0 and you do not plan to manage it through an upper layer of software, then a composite primary key is the way to go. In all other cases I would choose to have a single primary key `ApplicationID` and have an additional unique constraint over `(StudentID, JobID)`.

Comment: There is a third reason (IMHO): in the future, an extra key column "start_date" could be needed in the application table, to allow for the same person to get the job, quit it, and be hired again.

Comment: Indeed, this looks like a completely valid scenario which questions even the uniqueness of the `(StudentID, JobId)` combination.

Comment: `{studentId, JobId, start_date}` would form a natural PK. (but you could run into NULLability problems for the two FKs; best to define them NOT NULL anyway) (and/or possibly keep the surrogate to allow for future "key" updates in `{studentId, JobId, start_date}` )